# How to override register_argc_argv in PHP?

Tags: php, argv, command-line-interface, argc, ini-set

I'm using a shared host (fasthostingdirect) and for some reason they have this flag turned off by default. This means I'm unable to access PHP command line parameters... unless I use the `-n` (= `--no-php-info`) flag after `php.exe`.

Have tried `ini_set('register_argc_argv', 1)` in my php file but it has no effect. Am guessing this is due to the clamped down nature of the hosting provider, however they don't stop the `-n` option - not sure of the other implications of using this though. Does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: just move hosts. Trying to override their settings is a great way to get kicked off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ini_set('register_argc_argv', 1)` does not work because by the time the code is executed, they have already been registered (or not).

It seems you are able to run `php` directly, so copy your own `php.ini` file and pass it:

```
php -c yourphp.ini
```

Answer (score 9):

No need to create a whole new ini file, just use the `-d` flag

```
php -d register_argc_argv=1 myscript.php
```

Comment: WOOO this worked!! I was trying to run a php file from crontab and was not able to get url parameters, but this worked! thanks so much.