# Python script calling PHP script while passing $_GET parameters

Tags: php, python

I'm currently using `subprocess.call(["php", "test.php"])` in my python script to call a PHP script.

I would like to know if it's possible to pass `$_GET` parameters to the script while calling it. If it's possible how would I do it?

This is what I'm trying to get:
"`subprocess.call(["php", "test.php?i=3"])`"

This is my current code:
**test.py**

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["php", "test.php"])
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['i'];
?>
```

Comment: are you serving this php scripts under apache or fpm? why not use requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: No you won't be able to do this. You need to edit the php script and get it to parse `$argv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following with your Python passing in as many params as you'd like.

```
subprocess.call(["php","-f","test.php","param0:value0", "param1:value1"])
```

Now in PHP:

```
<?php
$_GET = array();

foreach($argv as $key => $pair) {
    if ($key == 0) { //skip first element which is script name (test.php)
        continue;
    }

    list($key, $value) = explode(":", $pair);
    $_GET[$key] = $value;
}
```

This manually parses `$argv` and populates `$_GET` for you so you only have modify the beginning of your PHP file.

This is an imperfect solution if your key or value have the same value as the `:` delimiter. An even better way would be to pass in the parameters via a JSON string. Something like:

```
subprocess.call(["php","-f","test.php", json.dumps(your_dictionary)])
```

and in PHP

```
<?php
if ($argc > 1) {
  $json_str = $argv[1];
  $_GET = json_decode($json_str);
}
```

and finally as suggested by user574632, you can wrap this code with the following `if` statment to ensure it doesn't interfere if you're still running it as a web-script as well.

```
if (php_sapi_name() == 'cli') {
  //execute in here *only* if run from the command-line
}
```

Comment: Populating GET manually suggests the script already works with get vars, and is therefor perhaps used from command and web, in which case a conditional check for `PHP_SAPI == 'cli'` might be in order

Comment: So I tried `subprocess.call(["php", "-f", "test.php", "1234", "3", "s"])`As for my php script it looks like this: `echo var_dump($argv)` and I'm getting `NULL` I even tried using a foreach loop to print all the values and I'm not getting anything back

Comment: Take this one step at a time - first call `php -f test.php 1234 3 s` manually from the command-line.

Comment: So I called `php -f test.php 1234 3 s` in the command line alone, I got the same results: `NULL` with a `count()` of `0` [php code](http://puu.sh/949w5.png) [results](http://puu.sh/949zT.png)

Comment: Post the beginning of the file to the part where you `var_dump`

Comment: Here's the official documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php As you can see it's quite simple. Try create a new test file with nothing but `<?php var_dump($argv);` Then you can find the source of your `NULL` problem.

Comment: New php: `<?php var_dump($argv);` Console line: `php -f t2.php 1234 3 s` Result: `NULL` Something with `$argv` just doesn't want to work :(

Comment: Your problem seems to have something to do with setting `register_argc_argv`. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459959/php-how-to-override-register-argc-argv - you can follow that advice or just edit your php.ini file, and set `register_argc_argv = On`

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't call it like that, more like this:

`subprocess.call(["php","-f","test.php","1"])`

Where 1 is the value of the argument. Then, in your script:

```
<?php
echo $argv[0];
?>
```

This gives you the value. My python is a bit rusty, but that's the basics.