# register_argc_argv can't be set via ini_set

Tags: php-ini, php, ini-set

i have following problem...

i have a webapplication and i want to use

```
register_argc_argv
```

in my php.ini it is turned off

```
Directive           Local Value    Master Value
register_argc_argv  Off            Off
```

now the problem is, i can't access the php.ini file directly because its on a hosted sever.
and actually even if i could, i don't want to turn on the master value.

in my `index.php` the first rows are:

```
<?php
    # Config
    require_once( "php/config.php" );

   // some more of my source
?>
```

in the config.php my source starts like this:

```
<?php

    ini_set( "register_argc_argv",          "1" );
    ini_set( "display_errors",      "1" );
    ini_set( "display_startup_errors",  "1" );

    // some more of my source
?>
```

but it won't turn on.

#### Question:

Am i doing something wrong ?

Is there a solution for this?

Could this be blocked by provider ?

#### What i have tried:

- ini_set( "register_argc_argv",          "1" );
- ini_set( "register_argc_argv",          1   );
- ini_set( "register_argc_argv",          "On" );
- ini_set( "register_argc_argv",          true );

And no [PHP: How to override register_argc_argv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459959/php-how-to-override-register-argc-argv) is not a dublicate because

1. this answere doesn't work for me
2. you see my first line and there is nothing executed befor

Comment: register_argc_argv is PHP_INI_PERDIR, meaning that it can only be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (that latter since PHP 5.3)

Comment: @MarkBaker could you tell me whats the correct .htaccess entry to do this ? gues google doesn't likes me :D `php_flag register_argc_argv On`causes an internal server error 500

Comment: @MarkBaker it seems like the server runs php in CGI-Mode so i can't use .htaccess to set flags like `php_flag register_argc_argv On`.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in CLI mode? Maybe a word with the hosting company may be useful?

Comment: actually i don't want to change any mode :) just want to set the flag. but in fact that this is getting a big deal i decided to leave it like this :)

Comment: i think i got some wrong anyway... i thought i can write a function like `function test(){ var_dump($argv);}` and if i call it i pass as may values i want... i know i could use a array for this but that's a other story :D thx anyway